# Dynamically show clicked image MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razorengine

I am new to MVC and I would like to ask a relatively simple question! I have an Index page with 2 pictures that are links. They both go another page, named "Page", and when this page opens, I want it to render the image that I just clicked on. Here is a snag from the Index page:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<h2>Column 1</h2>
    <a href="@Url.Action("NewPage", "Page")">
        <img src="~/Images/ball.jpg" />
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <a href="@Url.Action("NewPage", "Page")">
        <img src="~/Images/ball1.jpg" />
    </a>
</div>`
```

So if I click on "ball.jpg", I would like only that to render in the new page, and the same for "ball1.jpg".
The Controller for "NewPage":

```
namespace MVC.Mine.Controllers
{
    public class PageController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Page
        public ActionResult NewPage()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to pass a parameter to the method which identifies the image

Answer (score 0):

You can update your link's `href` attribute value to pass a unique key as the querystring parameter value.

For example, with your current code, the image file name can be passed.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("NewPage", "Page",new {id="ball"})">
    <img src="~/Images/ball.jpg" />
</a>
<a href="@Url.Action("NewPage", "Page",new {id="ball1"})">
    <img src="~/Images/ball1.jpg" />
</a>
```

Now make sure your NewPage action method accepts this string value in a parameter named id

```
public ActionResult NewPage(string id)
{
  var fileName=id+".jpg";
  return View(fileName);
}
```

Since you are passing the string value(file name) to the view, make sure it is strongly typed to string type.

```
@model string
<h2>Going to display the image clicked</h2>
<img src="~/Images/@Model" />
```

If you are showing the images for records from database table(s), you should pass the unique id(primary key) from which the image info can be easily retrieved in your NewPage action method.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I follow the first 2 parts, but the 3rd part I am not completely following.

Comment: you said you want to show the clicked image in the next page. So pass the image name from your action method to the view and in the view use that to build the image `src` property value. Hope that makes sense